# Savetxt file for images properties in a loop in python

Tags: python, image

I create a program that calculates number os pixels of certain value of temperature in a Satellite image. I used:

```
for infile in glob.glob(*.tif)
```

for open all .tif images in a loop.The program is working fine, and print in the terminal de name and de pixels number of all images.
But when i use:

```
np.savetxt("pixels.txt", (File, pixelstemp1, pixelstemp2), fmt="%1s", delimiter=' ')
```

only saves the pixels number of the last image in the txt file. How can i do for save in a txt file the number os pixels of all images?

```
from pylab import *

import numpy

import glob, os 


for infile in glob.glob("*04.tif"):
# pretend the rest of this is indented another level

dir, file = os.path.split(infile)
file, ext = os.path.splitext(infile)
sat=imread(infile)
satnovo=where(logical_and((418.-sat)-273.15>=-90,(418.-sat)-273.15<=-31),(418.-sat)-273.15,(660.-sat)/2-273.15)
temperatura=[-80,-70,-60,-50,-40,-30]
mask1=where(logical_and(satnovo<-30,satnovo>-80), 1,0)
mask2=where(logical_and(satnovo<-40 ,satnovo>-80),1,0)
mask3=where(logical_and(satnovo<-50, satnovo>-80),1,0)
mask4=where(logical_and(satnovo<-60, satnovo>-80),1,0)
mask5=where(logical_and(satnovo<-70, satnovo>-80),1,0)
x1=ma.masked_object(mask1,0)
pixels1=ma.count(x1)

x2=ma.masked_object(mask2,0)
pixels2=ma.count(x2)

x3=ma.masked_object(mask3,0)
pixels3=ma.count(x3)

x4=ma.masked_object(mask4,0)
pixels4=ma.count(x4)

x5=ma.masked_object(mask5,0)
pixels5=ma.count(x3)

print infile,pixels1,pixels2,pixels3,pixels4,pixels5
a=np.array([infile,pixels1,pixels2,pixels3,pixels4,pixels5],dtype=object)
np.savetxt("contapixels.txt",a[None],fmt='%1s', delimiter=' ')
```

Comment: You need to show us the rest of your loop -- and maybe the rest of your code -- the problem isn't in those lines.

Answer (score 0):

As agf notes, there isn't any error as such in the few lines you've provided, but from your description I think you are calling  `np.savetxt` for each image? If so, you'll overwrite `pixels.txt` on each pass. You want to either store all the data in some temporary list and write it at the end:

```
pixeldata = []
for infile in glob.glob("*.tif"):
    # Do processing
    pixeldata.append((infile, pixelstemp1, pixelstemp2))
np.savetxt("pixels.txt", pixeldata, fmt="%1s", delimiter=' ')
```

Or you could open the file and then append to it in every pass through the loop. However, then you can't use `np.savetxt`, so the method above is probably better.